# How do you read excel sheets using index instead of name with pandas.read_excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I know this is easily done with pandas.io.parser ExcelFile but the documentation says that they are dropping ExcelFile from future versions of pandas so I was wondering how to do this with its replacement read_excel().

The documentation says that you can use a sheet index by doing the following:

```
read_excel('path_to_file.xls', 0, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
```

Every time I try this I get the following error:

```
XLRDError: No sheet named <0>
```

Comment: Which version are you on?

Comment: I just realized that 0.13 hasn't been released yet. I'm on 0.12 which is why it isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're on the wrong version, this feature is new to version 0.13, which hasn't been released just yet.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I didn't realize 0.13 hadn't been released yet.

Answer (score 3):

The direct answer to your question is that this is a new feature for 0.13. That said, pandas is not planning to remove the ExcelFile class altogether (since you might want to read multiple sheets or be able to introspect sheet names): [it was just removed from the `pandas.io.parsers` namespace](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3717) to be consistent with the general naming scheme for IO functions (`read_clipboard` and `to_clipboard` underwent the same change).

`ExcelFile` and `ExcelWriter` will both continue to be available from the toplevel namespace (i.e. `from pandas import ExcelFile, ExcelWriter`).